# Stack Overflow server was down

Tags: discussion, support

A few hours ago I saw the following error when trying to access Stack Overflow:

[image: Error 521]

What's gone wrong?

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had outbound issues on the ISP which our HSRP was pointing to this morning for a bit. We have failed over the outbound traffic and are hoping to hear soon what their issue was a few hops away.

There will be a postmortem on http://stackstatus.net/ as soon as we have one. As always, follow [@StackStatus](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) for updates if you're curious.